# Is there a term for a chord progression that chromatically ascends or descends an octave?

Tags: theory, terminology, chord-progressions

I've noticed a pattern in music that is very interesting where a progression will start with one chord and chromatically ascend or descend until the starting chord is reached again.

For example: a descending progression that has this pattern would look something like this:

```
C   G7/B   Bb   F/A   Ab   G   D/F#  F  C/E Cm/Eb  D  Eb7/Db  C
```

The bass chromatically moves by half step down 12 times until reaching the first chord. Does this type of progression have a name?

Comment: I'm not sure it has a name, but it's really a bunch of deceptive progressions: root moves up a fifth, "resolves" to the flat mediant; up a fifth, etc....

Comment: @Patrx2 I know there are similar progressions out there and this one was just one I've been playing with for a while. I'm pretty sure there is one like this in somewhere in Mozart's Requiem (Lacrimosa if I remember correctly).

Comment: I'll have to check. I've seen similar in the literature myself (parallel first inversion chords, maybe?), but they rarely go full circle (or they go _past_ full circle). The practical problem with a full circle sequence of any sort is that it can give the impression of treading water.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it is called an omnibus progression.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This type of progression is called an **Omnibus Progression**.  It is a variation on the *lament bass* which is a figure where bass moves by a 4th connecting all chromatic notes in between.  The Omnibus Progression most notably features a chromatically-descending bassline that traverses an octave.  Additionally, the progression may also support a chromatically ascending S, A, or T line that ascends an octave simultaneously.

Here is a link to read more:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnibus_progression

Comment: Can an omnibus progression also ascend the chromatic scale, or is there another term for that?

Comment: @Kevin, reread the last full sentence of my answer. :)

Comment: old question, but for who looks this up, this is often called a "line cliché" in jazz

Answer (score 0):

One could also call this a *descending bassline* type of progression. Descending basslines are a powerful device that can unify a seemingly atonal chord sequence.